# li element stored on local stotarge doesn't show off on the screen

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a project where I need to ask the user for an input and when the user clicks on the button the input get stored in local storage and displays on the screen, I want each time that the user gets on the page the input show off as a li element, but the problem is that the input shows off on the document only once, while refreshing the page, the li element disappears but the key and the value are still stored on the Local Storage.

Here's a part of my JavaScript.

```
const input = document.querySelector('#text-input');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#add-plan-btn');
const ol = document.querySelector('ol');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', displayInput);

function displayInput(){
    // this function shows the input on an li element
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    window.localStorage.setItem('plan', input.value);
    li.textContent = localStorage.getItem('plan');
    ol.appendChild(li);
}
```

here's my html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Plan Maker</h1>
        <div class="input-plan">
            <input type="text" id="text-input" placeholder="enter here...">
            <button type="submit" id="add-plan-btn">Add</button>
        </div>
        <ol></ol>
   </div>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that happened because you call `displayInput` function on click and may you will need to call it on page load

Comment: Show your html and say what exactly you want

Comment: I've posted my html

Comment: is there an event to making me call it on page load ?

Comment: Do you need after refresh page, all li that added before, shows in body?

Comment: yes, I want all li that the user inputs show on the page after refreshing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to save `ol.innerText` in local storage and on page load you may need to check if local storage has value, create some `li` based on storage value and append to `ol` tag

Try this one:

```
 const input = document.querySelector('#text-input');
 const addBtn = document.querySelector('#add-plan-btn');
 const ol = document.querySelector('ol');

 addBtn.addEventListener('click', displayInput);

 var data = localStorage.getItem('plan');
 if (data) {
     var lst = data.split("\n");
     lst.forEach(t => ol.innerHTML += "<li> " + t + "</li>");
 }

 function displayInput() {
     // this function shows the input on an li element
     let li = document.createElement('li');
     li.textContent = input.value;
     ol.appendChild(li);
     window.localStorage.setItem('plan', ol.innerText);
 }
```